# Vuetify TreeView can't break text using css

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I can't seem to figure out how to get the long text in the following codepen to break and wrap. It goes off screen making the append button unclickable. I've tried every css rule I can think of.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/roZMjg

```
<div id="app">
  <v-modal>
    <v-container class="modal-container">
      <v-card>
  <v-treeview :items="items">
                <template slot="prepend" slot-scope="{ item, open, leaf }">

                </template>
                <template slot="append" slot-scope="{ item, open, leaf }"><v-btn small>Do Action</v-btn></template>
              </v-treeview>
        </v-card>
    </v-container>
  </v-modal>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      item: null,
      items: [
        {
          id: 0,
          children: [{
            id:1,
            name: "Child Text",
          }],
          name: "Long Text - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        },
        {
          name: "Short text"
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.v-treeview-node__content, .v-treeview-node__label {
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
.v-treeview-node__root {
  height: auto;
}
```

... will fix it.

Documentation: [flex-shrink](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-shrink-property).

Updated pen: https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/pqONvz

Comment: Thanks but it still looks like it's overflowing onto the "Short Text" and is overflowing past the vue card. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: @als, I didn't check it on a narrow screen. Updated now. It needed removing the hard-coded height.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.v-treeview-node__label{
  white-space: normal !important;
}
</style>
```

If you use Vue just add this App.vue

For default **white-space** sets *nowrap*. Thats why this shows:

"Very long text abou..."

After addition of this lines that will be:

"Very long text about
something important"